# ImageMagick annotate with PHP variable

Tags: imagemagick

I currently run the following command to annotate an image with the variable `$handle`

When running on a LAMP, everything worked fine and the `$handle` variable was put into the image. However running on a WAMP, the two apostrophes around the variable are being included into the variable. Which adds a ' to the front and end of the variable. Here is what I'm running. Any ideas why?

```
exec("C:\ImageMagick\convert $final -font handle_font.ttf -pointsize $font_size -fill 
black -annotate $pos_black '$handle' -fill white -annotate $pos_white '$handle' 
-flatten $final");
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows you need to swap the ' for " and in your case escape it with a \

```
\"$handle\"
```

Write your code like this and you can then echo out the $cmd and see what it contains:

```
$cmd = " $final -font handle_font.ttf -pointsize $font_size -fill black -annotate $pos_black \"$handle\" -fill white -annotate $pos_white \"$handle\" -flatten ";

echo $cmd.'<br>';

exec("C:\ImageMagick\convert $cmd $final");
```

Comment: I've tried doing this, but nothing gets annotated then. I don't see any text.

Comment: @Jako I assume there is an difference between the black and white text position.

Comment: Yes, it's just a 1px difference for a text shadow.

Comment: This is what it echos. `1.jpg -font handle_font.ttf -pointsize 26 -fill black -annotate +167+161 "@TEST" -fill white -annotate +167+160 "@TEST" -flatten` and same result with no text showing.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with me trying to add the @ symbol to the handle. If I remove '$handle' and just use $handle with no @ sign it works. But I need the @ included.

Comment: What happens if you use &#64;

Comment: I use XAMPP and I tried hard coding in @TEST, putting $handle = '@TEST' and $handle = "@TEST" and it worked every time. You could try the three different methods I tried and see if one of them works which may narrow the problem down. I wonder if $handle = '^@TEST' or $handle = '%@TEST' would work. There could be a problem with the version of IM you are using.